# RabbitMQ into AWS Redshift using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-redshift

I have a RabbitMQ consumer listening to a queue in RabbitMQ and receiving event data in NodeJS. I would like to have the consumer send each data event to AWS Redishit (possibly using their JavaScript SDK), but I cannot find any examples of how to do this, nor can I find any clarification of the process in Amazon's documentation.

How do I send data in NodeJS to Redshift using the AWS JavaScript SDK?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: It depends on the amount of data you want to ingest this way. Is it small (dimension changes) or large (events)? Anyway, you put data into Redshift through SQL (INSERT or COPY) using JDBC/ODBC drivers.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using a PostgresSQL library to connect to RedShift and perform inserts that way.

Comment: COPY is better if you have many records.

Comment: It's an ongoing stream not a bulk set, so INSERT was the right choice I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) I was able to open a connection pool to Redshift and perform INSERT commands from there. Fast, and lightweight - even under considerable load.